# How do I change the text input underline that comes up when clicked on in css

Tags: html, css, forms, input

Whenever I click on a text input in a form, a green underline comes up which doesnt really go along with the primary colours of the website I am currently working on. How do i change it to purple from green?( > Image for reference since I can't include images in my posts yet )
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEBk7.jpg

Comment: I think that is a border-bottom, just do `border: none;` ... can you share the code you used to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Here is the main idea, according to my knowledge we have 3 states for input,
- `active`,`focus`,`hover`.
- when you are selecting it's on the active mode, while you are selecting it by pressing `tabs` key it's in the focus mode and when you `mouseover` it it's in the hover mode.
- So to modify t's styling in this three mode, I have shown in example with `input:focus`,`input:hover` and `input:active` selectors and than apply CSS. You can play with it and apply same scenario in your question.
- I have also added all three modes for better understanding.

  ```css
  .main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: cenetr;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .allstate>input,
  span input {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  }

  .allstate>input:hover,
  .allstate>input:focus,
  .allstate>input:active {
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid purple;
  }

  .modes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 15px;
  }

  .modes span input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .active input:active,
  .hover input:hover,
  .focus input:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid purple;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="main">
    <span class="allstate">All states: <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter some data" /></span>
    <div class="modes">
      <span class="active">only active state: <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter some data" /></span>
      <span class="hover">only hover(mouse over) state: <input type="text"  value="" placeholder="Enter some data" /></span>
      <span class="focus">only focus state: <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter some data" />(outline won't appear as it's focus only)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```